# Where does the Bessel function bound $|J_{\nu}(z)| \leqslant C|z|^{-1/2}$ come from?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, special-functions

I've come across the following bound for $J_{\nu}$, the Bessel function of the first kind. It says that

$$\displaystyle |J^2_{\nu}(z)| \leqslant C_{\nu}|z|^{-1},$$

where $C_{\nu}$ is some constant depending on $\nu$. This would imply that $|J_{\nu}(z)| \leqslant C_{\nu}|z|^{-1/2}$. I've tried to prove this myself using the asymptotics of the Bessel function, which I found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/177247/363087). I found that

$$\displaystyle J_{\nu}(z) = -\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi z}}\sin(z + a\nu) + O(z^{-3/2}),$$

where $a = -\frac{2\nu - 1}{4}.$ Doesn't this surely give us that $|J_{\nu}(z)| \leqslant C_{\nu}|z|^{-1/2} + C^{\prime}_{\nu}|z|^{-3/2}$? Why are we able to rid ourselves of the $|z|^{-3/2}$ term? Or is this derived in a completely different way altogether?

We easily get the bound if $|z| \geqslant 1$. But what about $0 < |z| < 1$? Is there some other asymptotic expansion I should be using for small $|z|$?

Comment: Is the bound at the top supposed to be -1 or -1/2? Because it is -1/2 in the title and later in the question

Comment: I took square roots (the term on the LHS is $J_{\nu}^2$ rather than $J_{\nu}$).

Comment: For $z$ in a bounded region, such an inequality would follow immediately if Bessel functions $J_\nu$ were bounded near zero, which would follow from a different asymptotic expansion (one near zero, not near infinity).