# Convergence of sum involving Bessel function of the first kind

Tags: real-analysis, summation, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, analytic-number-theory

I am interested in finding any upper bound for the following series:

$$\displaystyle f(x) := \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^d \backslash \{0\}} |n|^{-d/2}J_{d/2}(k|n|)e^{inx},$$

where $d \geqslant 2$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, $k > 0$ is a positive constant, and $J_{\nu}$ is the Bessel function of the first kind. (For background, this sum arises in the study of the $L^p$-norms of the remainder in the (generalised) Gauss circle problem.) The sight of the exponential made me immediately want to take absolute values. However, using the bound $|J_{\nu}(z)| \leqslant C_{\nu}|z|^{-1/2}$, which comes from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/177118/363087) for large $z > 0$, then we get:

$$\displaystyle |f(x)| \leqslant C_d \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^d \backslash \{0\}}|n|^{-\frac{d+1}{2}},$$

and this series diverges, since it would converge only if $d < 1$, which is impossible (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1949932/363087) for the details). So bounding via modulus does not seem fruitful. Therefore, it seems more logical to exploit the positive-negative cancellation of the terms of the Bessel function. We could use the asymptotic expansion:

$$ J_\nu (x) \sim \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}} \cos \left( x - \frac{2 \nu +1}{4} \pi \right) + O \left( \frac{1}{x^{3/2}} \right), \;\;\;\;x \to \infty,$$

but then the $O(x^{-3/2})$ term forces us to take $d = 2$ rather than get a sum which converges for general $d$. Does anyone have any better ideas for how we could find an upper bound for this series? Are there any known results for similar sums?

Comment: Use the asymptotic expansion of $J_{\nu}(x)$ with more than one term. You should be able to find this in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik (8.451.1). In particular, use enough terms (which will depend on $d$) such that the remainder converges.

Comment: Also when $d$ is odd, this Bessel function is particularly simple, because this asymptotic expansion actually terminates. See Gradshteyn and Ryzhik (8.461.1).