# Lower Bounds for Bessel Functions of the First Kind

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, asymptotics, special-functions

Let $J_{\nu}$ denote the Bessel function of the first kind. By considering the asymptotics of the Bessel function, as given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/177247/363087), we have that, as $z \rightarrow \infty,$ one has:

$$\displaystyle |J_{\nu}(z)| \leqslant C_{\nu}|z|^{-1/2},$$

where $C_{\nu}$ is some constant depending on $\nu$. My question is simple: is there a similar lower bound for $J_{\nu}$? I've searched for some bounds online, but none seem to give a lower bound for $J_{\nu}$. Instead, they give lower bounds for products or quotients of Bessel functions. Does anyone know of a lower bound, preferably one that consists of powers of $|z|$, as $z \rightarrow \infty$?

For some context, I'm trying to find a lower bound so that I can bound a particular sum from below. I've found identities involving modified Bessel functions, but they all seem to give bounds on $\frac{I_{\nu}(x)}{I_{\nu}(y)}$.

Comment: Do you want it in the same limit as this bound?

Comment: Yes -- I'll add this to the OP.

Comment: I see. Do you know of any lower bound, then?

Comment: Nemo is saying that if there were any explicit expression for a lower bound for $|J_\nu(z)|$ then it would be about as complicated as $J_\nu(z)$ itself because the lower bound would have to contain *at least* all of the information about the zeros of $J_\nu(z)$ (which cannot themselves be written in closed form).

Comment: $J_\nu$ has infinitely many zeros, so it cannot have a lower bound.